# Second-order statistics estimator functions in the spatial point process

Tags: statistics, spatial, kernel-density, spatstat

I'm running into a problem with edge corrector position perception.
I would like to know when the edge corrector is placed in the numerator and when it is placed in the denominator, for example when estimating the K ou inhomogeneous K function and its extensions.
Below are two estimators of the same function but with edge correctors in different positions.

[image: Homogeneous g(u) function estimators]

Answer (score 1):

There is no essential conflict between these equations. The edge correction factor is denoted by `w_{y_i,y_j}` in equation (1) and by `e(x_i,x_j,r)` in equation (2). In both cases the edge correction factor appears in the numerator.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake sending the photos, I've already updated the equations